# I need only to scrape data-value "value"

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I need only to extract 153000.0

```
['<span data-name="price" data-value="153000.0">153\xa0000\xa0DT</span>']
```

how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `scrapy` and that value is in a `selector`, you can reference the attribute value using xpath like this:

```
from scrapy import Selector

body = '<span data-name="price" data-value="153000.0">153\xa0000\xa0DT</span>'
sel = Selector(text=body)

sel.xpath('//span/@data-value').extract_first()

# 153000.0
```

See more about `selectors` in the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).